# Move a DOM element whilst still keeping it in its own container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to move a DOM element inside the DOM but whilst still keeping it in its own container.

Take the following HTML:

```
<div class="contain">
  <div class="bit">A</div>
  <div class="bit">B</div>
  <div class="bit">C</div>
  <div class="bit">D</div>
  <div class="bit">E</div>
</div>
```

I want to put the `.bit` containing `A` to the end of this list, just below `E` whilst still keeping it inside the div `.contain`.

I have tried the following:

```
$('.contain').find('bit').first().appendTo('.contain');
```

and:

```
$('.contain').find('bit').first().insertAfter($('.contain').find('bit').last());
```

And neither of them work.

I have very little control over the HTML. For example I can't give each `.bit` its own unique ID.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try: `.find('.bit')`

Comment: `var c = document.querySelector(".contain"); c.appendChild(c.firstElementChild);`

Comment: @freedomn-m is right. The find function can accept classes, ids, tagnames and anything $() can accept: a selector expression. So a class has to be defined by the '.' in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *append* it to the *same* container and `A` is *moved* to the end of the list.

Your two attempts works - you have missed the `.` for the `find('.bit')` part.

See demo below:

```js
$('.contain').append($('.contain .bit:first-child'));

// the below works too
// $('.contain').find('.bit').first().appendTo('.contain');

// and even this works
// $('.contain').find('.bit').first().insertAfter($('.contain').find('.bit').last());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contain">
  <div class="bit">A</div>
  <div class="bit">B</div>
  <div class="bit">C</div>
  <div class="bit">D</div>
  <div class="bit">E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the class selector `.`, which you already use for `.contain`

```
$('.contain').find('.bit').first().appendTo('.contain');
```

working snippet:

```js
$('.contain').find('.bit').first().appendTo('.contain');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contain">
  <div class="bit">A</div>
  <div class="bit">B</div>
  <div class="bit">C</div>
  <div class="bit">D</div>
  <div class="bit">E</div>
</div>
```